# Dealing with custom exceptions in main script

Tags: php, exception

For this example, I am using the Mailgun library. They provide 5 different exceptions which can be caught.

My question is, how is this best to deal within my main script? I want to be able to catch all of them and error log, but having to catch all 5 individually, each time I use Mailgun feels messy.

My idea is to take each one and throw a standard Exception but I am not sure if this is correct?

```
public function sendMailPs($to, $from, $subject, $msgHtml, $msgTxt){

    $mg = Mailgun::create($this->config->key);
    try{
        $res = $mg->messages()->send('domain.com', [
            'from'    => $from,
            'to'      => $to,
            'subject' => $subject,
            'text'=> $msgTxt,
            'html'    => $msgHtml
        ]);
    } catch (HttpClientException $e){
        throw new \Exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
    } catch (HttpServerException $e){
        throw new \Exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
    } catch (HydrationException $e){
        throw new \Exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
    } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e){
        throw new \Exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
    } catch (UnknownErrorException $e){
        throw new \Exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
    }

}
```

Comment: Honestly I don't think there's a need to translate it to a standard exception, they already extend the base `Exception` class inherently.

Comment: Thanks for this. That was the first thing I tried but it did not catch it... however I have now retried it and it found it. Guess I must have had a typo or something in it first time. Thanks!

Comment: Generally this pattern is only useful when you need different behavior depending on what is thrown by the function you're watching. Eg if there was a "timeout exception" you may be inclined to re-try the request vs a "authroization exception" at which point you woudn't.

Answer (score -1):

1) You could reduce duplication by catch `RuntimeException` for when the exception extends a parent class.

```
final class HydrationException extends \RuntimeException implements Exception
```

2) You could use a case statement for the exceptions you are interested in and default the one you're not.

```
try
{
   // Code here
}
catch( Exception $e )
{
  switch( get_class( $e ) )
  {
    case 'HttpClientException':
    case 'HydrationException':
    case 'UnknownErrorException':
      throw new \Exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
  }
  throw $e;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public function sendMailPs($to, $from, $subject, $msgHtml, $msgTxt) {
    $mg = Mailgun::create($this->config->key);
    try{
        $res = $mg->messages()->send('domain.com', [
            'from'    => $from,
            'to'      => $to,
            'subject' => $subject,
            'text'=> $msgTxt,
            'html'    => $msgHtml
        ]);
    } catch (\Mailgun\Exception $e){
        throw new \MailgunException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
    }
}
```

You might lose additional $response from HttpClientException. So it is up to you to clean up. Or just use \Mailgun\Exception outside of above function.